# How to match words with random characters in between using Regex?

Tags: regex

Kinda hard to explain what I'm trying to do, so here's an example.

I'm looking for the word "bar" in the following string.

```
barristabrarbvvvaar
```

It should return `bar`, `brar` and `bvvvaar` since all of them have `bar` even with random characters in the middle.

How do I do that?

I tried

```
b.*a.*r
```

Comment: what you are using is greedy..you have to make it lazy using `.*?`

Comment: I used b.*a.*r . (Accidentally deleted previous response)

Comment: no problem..you just need to make it lazy using `.*?` instead of `.*`..`.*` is greedy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying a `global` match over the string, this regex will suffice

```
(b.*?ar)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7oC6/1)**

If there can be random characters between any two characters, you can use

```
(b.*?a.*?r)
```

Comment: How about this: `b.*?a.*?r` because i guess random character can also be in between 'a' and 'r'.